# Which one is grammatically right?

Tags: word-choice

1: I will get you confirm after breakfast.
2: I will make you confirm.
3: I will confirm you.

Which one is grammatically right among these sentences?
Would there be "confirm" or "confirmed" in the first sentence?

Comment: You haven't explained exactly what you *mean*, but I'm going to assume the context is something like a clerk assuring a potential client that his booking / reservation will be confirmed *(verified, authenticated, validated,...)* after breakfast. Your first attempt isn't valid English in *any* context, and the second would have to mean something like *After breakfast I will **force** you to confirm [something - your booking, perhaps]*. So only #3 really comes close, but it's a bit "jargonny". I'd prefer *I will **confirm your booking** after breakfast* or similar.

Comment: To add on to what @FumbleFingers said, the first one could be grammatically correct if you change ‘confirm’ to ‘confirmation’, which is the noun form such that the sentence becomes “I will get you confirmation after breakfast”. The third one would also be correct if the sentence were “I will confirm with you”

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

confirm (something) (with someone)

For example:

I will confirm with you after breakfast.

I will confirm the details with you after breakfast.